# Linking SQLite library using NDK on Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-ndk, static-linking

I need my app to use the latest SQLite as I am going to need FTS with ICU tokenizer which is not supported by Android.

I did not find any proper resources over the net that tells how to do it but one thing I think I could do is compile latest SQLite with NDK and write a JNI Wrapper on top of it and use it in my java android app.

I'm not sure how good or bad is the decision? Are there any better ways? Any resources that could help me in any way?

Comment: it is a good idea but it depends really on the dependencies of the libsqlite?are they available the ndk ready supported libs?if not then you will have to compile them all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I went ahead with this approach. I was able to compile the latest SQLite with my required tokenizer and didn't find any problem with it. Will update here if I find any issues in future.

Comment: I am also working as like what you did I haven't find any solution to build compile latest sqlite to support spatial queries could pls share your way of implementation on this?